# MySql in Python ValueError

Tags: python, mysql

> The ValueError: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 47
>         args = ('unsupported format character \'"\' (0x22) at index 47',)
>         with_traceback =

When I tried to execute this code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE "%'+bookname+'%" AND author LIKE "%'+author1+'%" AND written BETWEEN %s AND %s',(year1, year2))
```

When I input only bookname  and/or author it is ok.
When I input only year1 and year 2  it is also ok.

But if one of the( author, bookname) and (year1, year2) are inputed 
it does not work.

This code is working well.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE "%'+bookname+'%" AND author LIKE "%'+author1+'%"')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming You need a string for curser.execute() as follows;

```
SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE "%chuck%" AND author LIKE "%charmichel%" AND written BETWEEN 2015 AND 2017
```

Then you can use

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE "%'+bookname+'%" AND author LIKE "%'+author1+'%" AND written BETWEEN '+year1+ ' AND '+ year2)
```

or if you need a string like

```
SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE chuck AND author LIKE charmichel AND written BETWEEN 2015 AND 2017
```

Then you can use

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE '+bookname+' AND author LIKE '+author1+' AND written BETWEEN '+year1+ ' AND '+ year2)
```

Comment: cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM library WHERE book_name LIKE "%'+bookname+'%" AND author LIKE "%'+author1+'%" AND written '+year1+' AND '+ year2)  - tried this. It did not give error like before, but did not give any result as well  (((